# Error build VSTS: ## [error] Error: Unable to locate the 'nuget'

Tags: c#, build, nuget, azure-devops, specflow

I created a test project with C# + SpecFlow and I am trying to build the solution through VSTS, however in Nuget Restore is presenting the error below.

> 2018-08-07T15:29:39.6678023Z ##[error]Error: Unable to locate the
>   'nuget' [b3be7473-68ea-4a81-bfc7-9530baaa19ad] area. The service
>   containing that area may not be available in your region.
>   2018-08-07T15:29:39.6739350Z ##[error]Packages failed to restore

Would anyone know how to help me solve it or what? I already tried to check in the forum but none of the alternatives solved my problem.

Comment: guessing there is an outage.  I too am receiving this error on my latest build that was working last night.

Comment: @ewahner I think you are right, but I see no indication as such on http://status.nuget.org and such. No mention (that I can see) on twitter etc either...

Comment: It might be VSTS region specific. When building in an account in West Europe it doesn't work, but in a Central US account, it works.

Comment: Same issue think we are West Europe. Nuget official status page reports no errors, so don't know if the plugin/step has been updated and has broken. https://status.nuget.org/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got the same issue, resolved it by using NuGet restore version 1.x.

[image: Screenshot of fix]

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft has informed regarding this issue. Let's hope this issue will be fixed soon.

[Possible customer impacting event in all regions – 08/08 – Investigating](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/?p=17315)

Comment: We are working on rolling out a fix now which should resolve it in the next 30-60 minutes. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Since changing the version wasn't an option for me - I fixed this by just disabling the restore step in the build.

The build step does a restore anyway.

Comment: This also applies if your build definition relies on dotnet publish for building.

Answer (score 3):

We have rolled out a fix for this. Sorry for the disruption.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I am using .NET Core and it worked only by downgrading the version to 1.[image]

[image]

Although I have been using daily build for a long time, adding features and continuous delivery pipeline, Only today I had this issue.

Comment: Something must have happened. We have also using 2.* fo a long time and this error shown up just now. latest successful restore was 16h ago.

Comment: Same here, last successfully build was 15h ago.

Comment: Same issue here also CORE. Downgraded to 1.* seems to be a workaround for now